# order of inheritance in Python classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inheritance

I have a class `ExampleSim` which inherits from base class `Physics`:

```
class Physics(object):
    arg1 = 'arg1'
    def physics_method:
        print 'physics_method'

class ExampleSim(Physics):
    print 'example physics sim'
```

Imagine these classes containing lots of code.
Now I have made some modifications to `Physics` by defining a new class `PhysicsMod` and inheriting from `Physics`:

```
class PhysicsMod(Physics):
    arg1 = 'modified arg1'
```

but also to `ExampleSim` for which I created a new class `ExampleSimMod` and inherited from `ExampleSim`:

```
class ExampleSimMod(ExampleSim):
    print 'modified example sim'
```

My issue is that `ExampleSimMod` inherits from `ExampleSim` which inherits from `Physics` where i would like to have it inherit from `PhysicsMod` instead. Is there a way to do this? perhaps through `super()` or by multiple inheritance?

```
class ExampleSimMod(ExampleSim, PhysicsMod):
    print 'modified example sim'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can do multiple inheritance.

```
class Physics(object):
    def physics_method(self):
        print ('physics')

class ExampleSim(Physics):
    def physics_method(self):
        print ('example sim')

class PhysicsMod(Physics):
    def physics_method(self):
        print ('physics mod')

class ExampleSimMod(PhysicsMod, ExampleSim):
    pass

e = ExampleSimMod()
e.physics_method()
// output will be:
// physics mod
```

please note the order of class in `ExampleSimMod` matters. The's a [great article](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) about this.

I modified your code a bit for demonstration reason. Hope my answer can help you!