# The order of inherited classes matters in Python?

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I came across this error in my django application after hitting submit on a create or edit form:
`No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.`.

This was confusing because I have a *get_success_url* passed down through inheritance. To be clear, I have found the issue, but have no earthly idea why my solution worked.

Here was the code causing the error inside
*.../views.py*:

```
class FormViews():
    model = Ticket
    form_class = TicketForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('tickets:index')

class TicketCreate(CreateView, FormViews):
    template_name = 'tickets/ticket_create_form.html'
    model = Ticket
    form_class = TicketForm

class TicketUpdate(UpdateView, FormViews):
    model = Ticket 
    form_class = TicketForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

I created the *FormViews* class so there would not be any repeated code for the *model*, *form_class*, and *get_success_url*.

I was able to resolve this error by switching the parameters in my function definitions:

`class TicketCreate(CreateView, FormViews)` became `class TicketCreate(FormViews, CreateView)`

`class TicketUpdate(UpdateView, FormViews)` became `class TicketUpdate(FormViews, UpdateView)`

This fixed it. Now I redirect to the index page without any issues. Why is it that the get_success_url is recognized after switching the listed parent classes? I would have thought that the attributes and functions are inherited and recognized by Django regardless of order. Is this a Python or Django related issue?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086334/order-of-inheritance-in-python-classes

Comment: I'm not sure that article relates to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python every class has something called an MRO (Method Resolution Order), [this](https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/python-tutorial-understanding-python-mro-class-search-path) explains it pretty well. Your `FormViews` (also for the most part classes in python are singular) is more of a mixin, I would call it as such: `FormViewMixin`.

Since `CreateView` and `UpdateView` are proper classes that have `get_success_url` defined, the order ABSOLUTELY matters. So I would put the things you want "discovered", first.

```
class TicketCreateView(FormViewMixin, CreateView):
    ...
```

is what you want.

Comment: Hi Javier,  thank you for taking a look. Here is the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) for get_success_url. It does work with the solution mentioned in the post, but the problem I am having is with understanding why the order changed made a difference.

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum I see, yes, its called MRO, the order absolutely matters, the classes declared first will always be "discovered" first, so you want things that override functionality in front.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that get_success_url was defined inside the source code. I found it [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py).
So that makes sense why the error popped up.

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum If you remember, that is where i linked you originally ;) -- (see the link at the top of the original answer) https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64015833/1

Comment: Ahh oops, I did not see that link originally. Thanks again.