# Dealing with the Diamond Problem in Python

Tags: python, class, object, oop, inheritance

I'm working on a project where I need to implement multiple inheritance in Python, and I'm concerned about encountering the "diamond problem." I want to make sure I handle it properly to avoid unexpected behavior in my code.

I have a class hierarchy that involves multiple inheritance, and I'm worried about potential conflicts and ambiguities that may arise due to the diamond problem. Specifically, I have classes A, B, and C, where B and C both inherit from A, and I want to create a class D that inherits from both B and C.

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        print("A method")

class B(A):
    def method(self):
        print("B method")

class C(A):
    def method(self):
        print("C method")

class D(B, C):
    pass
```

I want to ensure that the method in class D behaves as expected and doesn't lead to unexpected behavior due to the diamond problem. What is the recommended approach to handle this situation in Python?

Specific Questions:

How does Python's method resolution order (MRO) work in this context, and how can I use it to my advantage?
Are there any best practices or design patterns to follow when dealing with the diamond problem in Python?
Are there any potential pitfalls or common mistakes I should be aware of when implementing multiple inheritance?
I appreciate any guidance or examples that can help me navigate through this issue and implement multiple inheritance in a safe and maintainable way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [order of inheritance in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086334/order-of-inheritance-in-python-classes)

Comment: read [this](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Answer (score -1):

Consider your code:

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        print("A method")

class B(A):
    def method(self):
        print("B method")

class C(A):
    def method(self):
        print("C method")

class D(B, C):
    pass
```

In this code, MRO (method resolution order) for these classes would be: "D->B->C->A". Following from that, if you call the method of a D instance, the program should print "B method".

If you want the program to use the method of a C class, then you need to switch inheritance order, you get:

```
class D (C, B): ...
```

If you're unsure what MRO your class follows, you could call **mro** attribute:

```
<class_name>.__mro__
```

To understand MRO better, you could visit [LinkedIn page](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/understanding-diamond-problem-python-ahmad-alharbi#:%7E:text=To%20address%20this%20issue%2C%20Python,class%20gets%20executed%20only%20once.) that provides brief explanation related to your problem.

If neither of these methods are appliable to your class, you could override your method in class D.

However, be careful when inheriting your classes because you might face TypeError. It occurs when developers incorrectly use MRO in python. As I explained above, the MRO follows the following structure: D (Subclass) -> B (LeftSubClass) -> C (RightSubclass) -> A (BaseClass). If you break that rule, the compiler is going to throw an error. Here's an example:

```
class BaseClass():
   pass

class RightSubClass(BaseClass):
    pass

class SubClass(BaseClass, RightSubClass)
   pass
```

In the following code, the MRO should be: "SubClass -> BaseClass -> RightSubClass -> BaseClass". However, this breaks the law of MRO where methods of the SubClass should be executed first but this code set BaseClass to be the second inherited class. Therefore, TypeError will be thrown. You could look it up on [another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214888/typeerror-cannot-create-a-consistent-method-resolution-order-mro) to dive deeper.

Here are sources that I used to explain this topic:

1. [scaler.com](https://www.scaler.com/topics/multiple-inheritance-in-python/) - this website explains multiple inheritance and addresses diamond problem
2. [tutorjoes.in](https://www.tutorjoes.in/python_programming_tutorial/Diamond_problem_in_python) - solution to diamond problem
3. [Stack OverFlow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214888/typeerror-cannot-create-a-consistent-method-resolution-order-mro) - TypeError explained
4. [educative.io](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-mro-in-python) - another explanation of TypeError
5. [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/understanding-diamond-problem-python-ahmad-alharbi#:%7E:text=To%20address%20this%20issue%2C%20Python,class%20gets%20executed%20only%20once.) - mentioned earlier